# rdlc report getting extra margin during printing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, printing, rdlc, reportviewer

I am working on a rdlc report.I use full width(7.6 inch) of rdlc.when i check it in pdf format using crome browser I see exactly what i design in rdlc where there is no margin.I set all margin 0 using report properties option.
But problem happens when i print that report,i am getting extra one inch margin around my rdlc content which is not in there when i see it in pdf view.

How can i get rid of that extra margin or reduce that margin or control that margin?
is there any way to control it or set print page margin from the code?

Answer (score 1):

Your print setup and properties needs configuration.
i think this post is useful [Every Other Page Is Blank](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrisbal/2006/08/10/the-every-other-page-is-blank-feature/)

Answer (score 0):

i use chrome print dialog for print.there i find a option "Fit to Page" under "Options".I unchecked that option.Then my report is stretches according to page size and take full width of my page and this is what I want.